# Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression with Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jslint

I'm using [JSLint][1] with ES6 style IIFE's in my Angular App and I get this error:

> Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression

On the following code:

```
{
  'use strict';
   angular.module('MyModule', []);
}
```

Should I omit 'use strict' in this case?

Comment: remove the `{` and the `}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the `{` and `}`, it should work then.